# http GET returning TOTALLY DIFFERENT HTML elements and innerHTML from what's seen on browser's DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, web-scraping, element

The Goal: 
To export entire HTML page (of this **specific url)** to 'newFileOnLocalDisk.txt' for offline data studying.

Problem Encountered:
Able to export HTML of this particular url into 'newFileOnLocalDisk.txt'  **... BUT ... exported HTML elements and values does NOT match what's on browser's DOM.**

```
const http = require('http');
const url = 'http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/securities/equities/prices/#/?filter=BS02&page=3';

const httpGet = url => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      http.get(url, res => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        let body = ''; 
        res.on('data', chunk => body += chunk);
        res.on('end', () => resolve(body));
      }).on('error', reject);
    });
};

async function exportToLocalHTMLfile () {
    const body = await httpGet(url);
        /*********************************************************
        * What's returned to console.log is totally different
        * from what is in browser's DOM Elements / inspect element
        * 
        * Question #1:
        * How can we export "as-is or in raw HTML" directly from  
        * less-friendly pages like this?
        * 
        *********************************************************/
        console.log(body); //<-- will be later exported to TEXT file. Codes removed to keep this article leaner.
    }

    exportToLocalHTMLfile();
```

`console.log(body)` returned the below excerpt. This is totally different from what's in browser's DOM element

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
<meta http-equiv="CacheControl" content="no-cache"/>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>

<APM_DO_NOT_TOUCH>
<script language="javascript">
//<![CDATA[

(function(){
    var securemsg;
    var packmsg;
    var CryptoUtils;

try{(function(){try{var _S,IS,lS=1,LS=1,ZS=1,__=1,i_=1,I_=1,j_=1;for(var J_=0;J_<IS;++J_)lS+=2,LS+=2,ZS+=2,__+=2,i_+=2,I_+=2,j_+=3;_S=lS+LS+ZS+__+i_+I_+j_;window.JS===_S&&(window.JS=++_S)}catch(l_){window.JS=_S}var L_=window.sdkljshr489=!0;function o_(S){window.sdkljshr489&&S&&(L_=!1);return L_}function O_(){}o_(window[O_.name]===O_);o_("undefined"===window.vodsS0);window.vodsS0=null;o_(/\x3c/.test(function(){return"\x3c"})&/x3d/.test(function(){return"0";"x3d"}));
var Z_=window.attachEvent||/mobi/i.test(navigator.userAgent),_ .... (end of excerpt)
```

For you info, the unreadable contents in 'newFileOnLocalDisk.txt' is 61,055 characters long. None of them resembled any data inside `id="bm_price_container"`

If there's better methods or strategies to achieve this task than `const http = require('http');` please point the way? Thanks in advance for your time and effort in shining light.

Comment: Your browser updates it's innerHtml based on what their <script> tag does, your node program doesn't do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Node.js module that would load the page in a headless browser to execute all JavaScript code in the page and update the DOM dynamically. For example, you can try [GoogleChrome/puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto(
      'http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/securities/equities/prices/#/?filter=BS02&page=3',
      { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' },
    );
    await page.waitFor(5000);

    const html = await page.content();
    console.log(html);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Just 1 last issue: Target is "Page 3", as specified in last character of this query string eg. [link] (http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/securities/equities/prices/#/?filter=BS02&page=3)

Somehow, _what's downloaded remains at Page 1_. 

Did you manged to download other pages beyond Page 1? What query string with luck?

Comment: @bg27 It seems the site resets queries from an external referer to page 1 and navigates to other pages via XHR/fetch updating the URL without reloading the page. You can try to read the puppeteer documentation about clicking on elements and waiting for responses or DOM changes to implement this navigation in the headless browser.